# What does "pa more" means in dota2 chatting

Tags: dota-2, terminology

These days I hear this from alot of people while they're losing. I initially thought, it's a sarcastic comment to tell someone to play phantom assassin, to showcase their new sets or pick pa even when a team already had enough carries. But I see people calling it even when there is NO pa in the game (neither sides) and also sometimes told to myself when I played support (full support with courrier, warding,pulling and baby sitting etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PA MORE** is a basic Filipino phrase which generally means to do something again or more frequently.

It is possible the phrase is used as a sarcasm in dota 2.

specially in `SE-ASIA` servers.

Comment: I don't think "pa more" can be described as a "basic" Filipino phrase. Aside from being very informal and often used as an insult, one of the words is not even in Filipino (that's literally the English word, "more" and means the same in English). i.e., Do [action] more (or again).

Answer (score 0):

"Pa more" is an informal phrase that means "to do, to be, or to have more of something". It is used to give more emphasis. And usually used in a positive encouraging way. No sarcasm intended.

Answer (score -3):

It is sarcasm, saying "do it again." Like "solo PA MORE", meaning, "go solo again" in a sarcastic way. It means that you should do the negative thing all over again without thinking, and the speaker is encouraging you to do it in a sarcastic way.

Comment: You're just repeating what the accepted answer said. Don't do that.

Comment: I find that this answer actually explains the phrase more accurately than the [currently accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/256989/4797), and it explains the phrase as used in the context of this game better. It is not a dupe due to the more detailed and accurate explanation.